# Spring integration sftp adapter update remote file permission

Tags: spring-integration, sftp

We are using the spring integration sftp outbound adapter to sftp a file to a remote server. The receiver has mentioned that the file we ftp needs to have read-write permission (chmod 777). Is there a way to set this through the outbound adapter so that the file is created with the right permissions?

Answer (score 1):

That is not currently supported; please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we'll consider adding it.

In the meantime, after uploading the file, you could use an `SftpRemoteFileTemplate` to change the mode.

```
    template.executeWithClient(new ClientCallbackWithoutResult<ChannelSftp>() {

        @Override
        public void doWithClientWithoutResult(ChannelSftp client) {
            try {
                client.chmod(...);
            }
            catch (SftpException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```